# How to drag a template which is a image in one div and drop it in another div so that it opens as a page?

Tags: html, jquery-ui

html:

```
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="one">
 <p id="drag1" ><img src = "e:\Atom\UI\images\Capture.PNG" alt="home page" /> </p>
 <p id="drag2"><img src = "e:\Atom\UI1\images\Capture2.JPG" alt="home page" /> </p>

 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-8"> <div id="droppable" class="ui-sortable" ><ol></ol></div></div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

jquery ui:

```
$(function() {

$( "#drag1" ).draggable({ appendTo: "body", helper: "clone"});
$( "#drag2" ).draggable({ appendTo: "body", helper: "clone"});

$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
drop: function(event,ui){
});
});
```

when the image is dropped in the droppable div we should be able to modify the contents of the page(template) dropped that is we can change the title of the page, add/delete textbox, button, label...etc

Comment: an image cannot be converted to a page. you need the template page saved somewhere. and retrieved on the drop event of the picture.

Comment: var dragId = ui.draggable.prop("id");
 if(dragId=="drag1"){                                                     $("#droppable").load("e:/Atom/UI1/html/home.html"); }  I tried this code but it is not working

Comment: You are confusing things. The page is located on your website, but when you reference using a drive letter it will search for the page on the client machine. You need to provide a relative path of the page on your website: eg. **www.mywebsite.com/mypages/home.html**